# Wireless problem with D-Link Dir 600

Tags: wireless-networking

I bought a week ago a D-Link Dir 600 router. Everything works fine as long as I connect the computers through LAN, but I have problems connecting to the wireless network. My laptop gets disconnected every 4-5 minutes. Any idea how can this be fixed or what could cause the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that it's true in your particular case, but in some instances when a router is capable of wireless-N and only some of the clients are N capable a frequent disconnect issue surfaces for one set of connection types until they are forced to A only, B/G mixed, or N only.  The solution for me most frequently was either upgrade all devices to N or set the capability level of the N devices to lower standards.

This problem is less evident in >=2+2/MIMO devices because in some instances they can have their different ins/outs on different frequency bands.  Ultimately, I think it comes down to different vendors dealing with band selection differently.